# Document not visually updating when inserting OpenXML into Office Online Word document

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office-js, ms-wopi

I'm using the OfficeJS API to insert some OpenXML into a Word document in Office Online server. I've also setup a custom WOPI host to handle the requests.

In my task pane addin, when I click a button an image is inserted into the document using the following code:

```
Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(getImageOOXML(), {
    coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Ooxml
},
```

When that code runs a PutFile request is made to the WOPI host and the document is saved.

The problem I'm having is that nothing visually shows in the document. An image should appear where the cursor is but it's not there. If I refresh the page with the Word editor, then the image shows up as expected.

I also tried using  an on-premise Sharepoint server that is linked to the same Office Online Server to edit a Word document. I used the exact same addin, and the image appears immediately as expected when the OpenXML is inserted.

I'm not sure why the document is visually updating with Sharepoint and not with my custom WOPI host. I noticed Sharepoint is using the Cobalt protocol whereas the custom WOPI host is not, but I don't think that should make a difference.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: Update: Tom Jebo from Microsoft has been able to replicate the issue and is looking into what may be causing it. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/671a4649-8566-4413-8eb9-dcd016635583/document-not-visually-updating-when-inserting-openxml-into-office-online-word-document?forum=os_office